# How to use source() on another notebook

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm used to separating my code in different files, and call those files when needed. I did not manage to call a notebook (.Rmd) with chunks using the *source()* function.

I **can** source a notebook, but it will run as a script (.R), working well for functions written as:

`test <- table(mydata$M1, mydata$M2FR)
test`

but returning errors (`attempt to use zero-length variable name`) for chunks as:

````
```{r}
test <- table(mydata$M1, mydata$M2FR)
test

```
````

Is there a way to use *source()* on a notebook with chunks, or should I design my files without chunks?

Comment: Provide an example of your data will be helpful

Comment: Please check Yihui Xie answer in linked question: `source(purl("file.R", output = tempfile()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile notebooks with

```
 rmarkdown::render("analysis.R")
```

But this will not leave the functions in your workspace, as the notebook is self-contained.